# SharePoint Online Copy a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

I have a pages library with a page that has the web parts and text layout I want to use for a few other pages in my library. The only things that will change on the new pages will be the text inside my content editor web part.

The pages should be independent of each other after I copy, but when I do the copy option, I notice it's creating a connection to see the "source" page under the files toolbar. This is fine as long as when I change the source page it doesn't change the destination pages as well.

From my understanding (thanks to the deleted comments below), this link to the "source" page won't push changes to the copied version, but this is not the best practice for what I'm trying to do.

Would the "best practice" be to use a page layout template?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this, but the pages are independent once created.  There is no dependency.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71833/discussion-on-answer-by-jammin4co-sharepoint-online-copy-a-page).